# How to plot multiple time series data in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I am totally new in R.. and i need to plot time series data like this:

Month     Revenue
20110101    12000
20110102    11000
20110103    10700
................
20170111    10400
20170112    10000

I load data from .csv and Date is stored as  a number. and i try  this code:

plot(R$Month,R$revenue,type = 'l')

[image]

Any idea how i can convert numbers on X as Dates and make better plot. Because this is not correct.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert to Date.

```
R$Month <- as.Date(R$Month, format = "%Y%m%d")

plot(R$Month,R$revenue,type = 'l')
```